# Can I force disable "requireInteraction" in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, notifications

I want to receive notifications from Chrome, but I am annoyed by notifications that require clicking on them to dismiss (i.e. YouTube). I believe this is the "requireInteraction" property in Web Notifications

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requireInteraction

Can I force this to false so I still receive notifications from YouTube, but they get dismissed automatically if I do not interact with them?